# How to substract two tall and skinny matrices using mapreduce?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to substract two tall and skinny matrices using mapreduce.
One matrice is stored in one file and other matrice is stored in other file.
How to apply mapreduce concept and then how to give command for input of two files to Hadoop simultaneously?(At present ,I am using Dumbo in python for Hadoop)

Can anyone suggest idea or source?

```
      !['''x=0,y=0,z=0,a=0'''
x=0
y=0
z=0
a=0
def mapper1(key1,value1):
    x=key1
    y=value1
    yield x,y
'''yield key1,value1'''
def mapper(key,value):
    z=key
    a=value
    yield z,a
'''yield key,value'''
def reducer(x,y,z,a):
    if x==z:
       res=math.abs(y-a)
       yield x,res
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import numpy as np
    import math
    import dumbo
    dumbo.run(mapper1,mapper,reducer)
'''e''']
```

I am getting an error: [1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfZMy.png

Comment: Can you show an example matrix and what you have tried till now?

Comment: Both the files which contain matrix is in sequence format and dimension is (38lakh,10).